# How can i get messages from Signalr using Jmeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr, jmeter-plugins

I want to automate REST API using Jmeter. My requirement is trigger and validate the signals generated from the field.Messages from the field like "communication lost" need to check whether this message reached API or not.These messages are developed using "signalr".Can anyone tell me how can i get the messages from signalr in Jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

As per SignalR main page:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available. **SignalR supports Web Sockets**, and falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers.

So my expectation is that you can use [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki/Features) plugin in order to test this functionality. The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), check out [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article for comprehensive information on installation, configuration and usage of the plugin for WebSockets load testing.

Comment: I tried with WebSocket Sampler,i am new to this so i dont know how to request data